# MySQL - Select concatenate 2 values with 1 id

Tags: mysql, select

For example, I have a table 'Map':

```
Map:

id | place
__________
1  | a
1  | b
2  | a
2  | b
2  | c
```

What MySQL query can I use for me to have the following results:

```
id | place
__________
1  | a,b
2  | a,b,c
```

Comment: What is the purpose of such results? You need to count something or ...? Please, don't get me wrong, but if you will, somehow, get the results as you wish, the PLACE column will return the string "a, b, c, etc".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [group_concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function for this. You can use it as follows.

```
SELECT id,group_concat(DISTINCT place ORDER BY place ASC SEPARATOR ',') 
FROM Map
GROUP BY ID
```